# How to burn confidential assets or pegged bitcoin on Bitcoin Liquid sidechain

Tags: sidechains, blockstream, liquid

I used to burn bitcoin sending to a bogus address like `1111111111111111111114oLvT2`

There is any equivalent confidential address for Elements/Liquid?

Answer (score 3):

destroyamount is the rpc call you are looking for

https://github.com/Blockstream/liquid/blob/3f937d39f7c516e49f62d05c12d41b63b79ca043/src/wallet/rpcwallet.cpp#L586

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add something about this. `destroyamount` is indeed the function used to burn assets in elements, but I'm now using a watch-only wallet for some reasons, and I found out that `destroyamount` will fail with `Insufficient funds` error because obviously I don't have any UTXOs I can sign directly with the wallet, and there's no `include_watching` options like other wallet methods have.

The way to do that is then to use `createrawtransaction` and add an output with `"burn"` as the address, which is documented in the help message, but what is not very clear is that you can also add `"burn"` as an address in the `output_assets` object with the id of the asset you want to burn. This is not very well documented in the help though, that only advertise the `"address"` or `"fee"` keys.

Besides, I was also confused by the fact that the help message seems to ask for a string `"hex"` as value for the key `"burn"`, but actually it is the amount as a float.

Anyway this should work, and allow us to create a transaction that burns some assets and can be signed on another device.